# What are CBP agents doing when deciding whether to allow a US lawful permanent resident to enter the US by car?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, driving, borders

When entering the US by car via a Sentri lane as a US lawful permanent resident (LPR), the CBP agent often takes over a minute on their computer to decide whether to allow the US LPR to enter the US, not counting the questions that they may ask, verifying that the US LPR looks at the same as on their Permanent Resident Card nor the quick visual inspection of the vehicle. This  makes me wonder: What are CBP agents doing when deciding whether to allow a US LPR to enter the US?

Comment: For comparison.  Do you know how long a US citizen (or an LPR other than you) takes to be processed under at the same entry point?  Because without a comparative analysis, asking what's special about your entry times is not really useful.

Comment: @PeterM nothing special about me

Comment: The opining about why it can't be faster doesn't make sense

Comment: @PeterM I'm not asking why it can't be faster.

Comment: Does it take you as long at the Canadian land border too?

Comment: @JonathanReez Sorry I don't remember. The last time I went through the Canadian land border, the CPB officer inspected my trunk and I believe almost sent me to the secondary inspection, which distracted me from paying attention to the rest of the encounter.

Comment: You literally said below "Thanks, wouldn't these checks be made automatically and take a few secs?"

Comment: @PeterM  you are commenting on the original question. The original question is "What are CBP agents doing when deciding whether to allow a US lawful permanent resident to enter the US by car?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A US Citizen just needs to confirm their identity. However, since as an LPR you don't have an inherent right of entry, the CBP officer needs to confirm, on top of your identity, that you're still in fact an LPR and that no further inspection is needed before admitting you.

For starters, they [need](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/211.1) to check your previous exits and entries to make sure that you haven't spent more than 1 year out of the country (in this case a REP would be required) or more than 2 years out of the country (in this case a SB1 visa would be required). There are some links in [this answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/23782/136) and comments to it.

They may want to check that you're not entering and leaving the country just to circumvent the above time limits (e.g.: that you're not entering for a week every half a year to avoid resetting your citizenship clock, or every year to avoid the REP/SB1 thing).

There may be additional checks that I can only speculate about that US citizens wouldn't need: cross-checks against immigration enforcement databases (ICE/USCIS), potentially maybe checking some crime databases (conviction of certain crimes may lead to invalidating your LPR status), and what's not.

As mentioned in the comments, these are very likely automated. But when entering by land, the CBP has no prior knowledge of your impending arrival (as opposed to sea or air travel, where the carriers provide the manifest and details about the passengers, ahead of time). So all the information needed cannot be pre-fetched from the various databases and needs to be accessed online while you're there, waiting. This takes time, even in the digital age.

There's also a customs check component, but it's no different for LPRs compared to anyone else.

---

If for whatever reason necessary information is not currently available, you may be referred to a "secondary inspection". This is true for anyone, not just LPRs. Same happens if there are some suspicions, or if there's missing documentation (e.g.: a US citizen arriving without evidence of their citizenship). Once all the necessary details are confirmed, the person would then be either admitted or denied entry, or may even be arrested (if, for example, there's an outstanding arrest warrant).

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't these checks be made automatically and take a few secs?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt they may be automated (in fact they very likely are automated), but especially on land crossings where the details about your arrival are not provided ahead of time as they are with air travel - these may take a bit longer than seconds since the data needs to be fetched from somewhere.

Comment: in addition, when deciding to admit anyone (even a citizen who cannot be excluded) the officers also need to decide whether or not to admit your stuff (which has no rights) and whether it needs to be looked through to make that determination. They may therefore be doing absolutely nothing during that "delay" but observing you to see how you feel about it and how worried you appear, since there is a common belief smugglers can be spotted from such things.

Comment: Yep, that's true, but that's not special to LPRs. The OP seems to be interested in what makes the LPR process stand out

Comment: A US citizen has to prove US citizenship just as much as an LPR has to prove lawful permanent residence.  But with an LPR, the officer also has to decide whether the traveler is an "applicant for admission" as defined in the Immigration and Nationality Act.  Mostly they're not.  There will be other differences in the process as well,

Comment: @phoog no, not just as much. A US citizen only needs to prove their identity. LPR, as I describe in the answer, is only applying for admission and other data points not necessarily in their possession may affect the decision.

Comment: That's simply not true. For example, a US citizen can show a driver's license, which proves Identity, but unless it's an enhanced license, which also proves citizenship, the officer will not admit the person without additional inquiries to establish whether the person is a US citizen. The idea that a person can be treated as a US citizen without proving that they are a US citizen makes no sense.  On top of that, most LPRs are not applying for admission, either.

Comment: @littleadv, if you insult people in comments they get deleted. If you repeatedly insult people and/or flag with false accusations you will get suspended. Respect that others have a different view. You made your point, they made theirs.

Comment: @phoog again, since you somehow got my previous comment deleted. You're wrong. There's no US law that provides for removal or denying entry to US citizen solely based on what piece of paper they happen to hold in their hand.

Comment: I didn't do anything to get your comment deleted. I never said that US law requires a US citizen to hold any given piece of paper, only that proving identity is not sufficient for a US citizen to gain admission to the US: the officer must be convinced that the person is a US citizen in order to admit the person as such, and the burden of proof lies on the traveler. Sure, a verbal claim of citizenship may be accepted with little investigation, but not necessarily. A US citizen born and raised abroad who has a foreign accent, for example, is unikely to be admitted without documentary evidence.

Comment: @phoog every edge case has an edge case, but if you need to add so many qualifiers to your claim - maybe I wasn't that wrong after all. You can admit a mistake once in a while, it will only show you're a human, not a troll.

Comment: @littleadv on the other hand, sometimes a counterexample is not an "edge case" but a demonstration that the rule is expressed incorrectly, which it is here: there is no rule that US citizens only have to prove their identity.  There is, however, a rule that "a person claiming U.S. citizenship must establish that fact to the examining officer's satisfaction" [8 CFR 235.1(b)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/235.1)).  The rest of that section discusses documentary requirements, which are subject to being waived, this one logically cannot be waived.

Comment: @phoog your logic is flawed. Or, rather, reading comprehension. 8 CFR 235.1(b) refers directly to 22 CFR 53. Which explicitly tells you that it *can* in fact be waived. For example, 22 CFR § 53.2(9) provides this exception waiver: *When the Department of State waives, pursuant to EO 13323 of December 30, 2003, Section 2, the requirement with respect to the U.S. citizen because there is an unforeseen emergency;"*

Comment: @littleadv 22 CFR 53 is cited with respect to the documentary requirements, not the requirement that the officer be convinced that the person is a US citizen.  This follows first from the use of the word "must" twice (since you mention reading comprehension).  This is a compound predicate, and the "as required" clause belongs only to the second part of the predicate.  More importantly, as I've been saying all along, this conclusion also follows logically: an officer cannot admit a person as a US citizen if the officer is not convinced that the person is a US citizen.  It's nonsensical.

Comment: @phoog if the person can prove their identity, there are many ways the CBP officer can confirm their citizenship status without documentation. For example, they can check whether I've been issued a Global Entry card, even if I don't have it in my possession. Or, they can confirm with the DoS that I've been issued a passport, even if it is not in my possession. The waiver then comes, if appropriate. I'm not disagreeing that this is an exceptional situation, but I'm saying that it is definitely possible and the CFR as you cited allows it.

Comment: Quote from your link: *A person claiming U.S. citizenship must establish that fact to the examining officer's satisfaction and must present a U.S. passport **or alternative documentation as required by 22 CFR part 53**.* The first "must", as I explained, doesn't mean that I as a US citizen absolutely must present a passport, otherwise the **or** part wouldn't be needed. The **or** part explicitly says that a waiver for documentation part can be given in some circumstances.

Comment: "if the person can prove their identity, there are many ways the CBP officer can confirm their citizenship status without documentation": that doesn't change the fact that the person proving identity is doing so as a means to proving citizenship, not as an end in itself.  But frankly, rereading the question, I wonder whether the premise is flawed: does processing an LPR in the SENTRI lane actually take longer than processing a US citizen?  Maybe US citizens also often have to wait more than a minute.

Comment: @phoog well, of course proving identity is a prerequisite to proving citizenship. You can prove that "phoog" is a citizen, but you also first need to prove that you are that "phoog". What I'm saying is that if absolutely necessary - a document proving that you are that "phoog" may be enough, the rest will come from other sources. Of course we're all required to carry passports when traveling. But yes, the law and the CFR allow for situations when we don't, if we have no other choice. Which was my point.

Comment: "well, of course proving identity is a prerequisite to proving citizenship": not necessarily.  Some years before 2001 I entered the US with the only evidence of my citizenship being a verbal claim of having been born in the US, a claim made more credible by a US driver's license.  There was no secondary inspection, no looking me up in any database, no "other sources."  The evidence of citizenship was tied to me, not to the document I used for identification.  Now things have obviously changed since 2001, but it is still more important to convince the officer of citizenship than identity.

Comment: @phoog you're actually reinforcing my argument and not undermining it. In your story you did prove your identity (you have shown your driving license), and you didn't have to prove your citizenship by showing any explicit document.

Comment: My point is that the evidence that I was a US citizen had nothing to do with my driver's license, which proved only that I had lived in the US two years earlier when it was issued.  The admission interview lasted maybe a minute, probably less.  They didn't look anything up; they just accepted a verbal claim without further investigation.  Your belief that I am saying one must prove citizenship with an explicit document is mistaken; I am only saying that a US citizen must convince the officer of that fact, which is a higher bar to pass than simply proving identity.

Comment: @phoog again, you think you're providing a counterargument, but you are in fact supporting my statement. You're showing an example where as a US citizen all you needed to *prove* was your identity. Just as I said. You claim you *convinced* the officer, but you also claim explicitly that you didn't need to *prove* anything.

Comment: @littleadv  but I did prove it.  I gave the officer evidence that I was a US citizen, and the officer accepted it.  If I had shown a foreign passport and spoken with a foreign accent, I might not have succeeded in proving my US citizenship, but I would have succeeded in confirming my identity.